# What could be wrong with this proof? (Every point of an open subset of a metric space is a limit point)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I was studying real analysis and to solve an exercise I came up with the following hypothesis:

*Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $A \subset X$ be an open set of $X$, then every point of $A$ is a limit point of $A$.*

I then proved that (or that is what i thought), but after that I realized that this may not be true in general (since, for example, in discrete metric space, singletons {x} are open sets but do not contain limit points). Here is my proof: (I would like to know if you can tell me what could be wrong with it)

Let $x \in A$ where $A$ is an open subset of a metric space $X$, lets suppose that $x$ is not a limit point of $A$, then there exists at least one $\epsilon >0$ such that the ball $B(x;\epsilon)$ does not contain any point of $A$ other than $x$, observe that for every $r$ such that $0<r<\epsilon$ the ball $B(x;r)$ also does not contain any point of $A$ other than $x$, then for every $y \in B(x;\epsilon)$ such that $y \neq x$ we have $y \in M-X$ so that the ball $B(x;\epsilon)$ is not contained in $A$. Also for every $0<\epsilon <s $ the ball $B(x;s)$ would contain every $y \in M-A$ that is in $B(x;\epsilon)$ and therefore there is no open ball centered at $x$ contained in $A$ contradicting the fact that $A$ is open. Hence, $x$ must be a limit point of $A$.

Comment: Metric spaces can be discrete. Consider for example a space with two points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then for every $y\in B(x,\epsilon)$ such that $y\neq x$ we have $y\in M-X$ so that the ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ is not contained in $A$.

It is entirely possible for no such $y$ to exist (e.g. in a discrete space), in which case $B(x,\epsilon)=\{x\}$ is contained in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

A space $X$ is discrete if and only if no subset of $X$ has a limit point. Your assertion is false for discrete spaces.